# How to convert a windows store app into windows phone 8.0 app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I need a guide to convert my working windows store app into a windows phone 8 app please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this automatically. Although there might be a decent amount of code you can reuse, thanks to WinRT/WinPRT similarities, you will still need to work on some platform-specific capabilities (e.g. storage).

My colleague, Rick Barraza, [put together a fantastic guide](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/C9Team/Migrating-the-Khan-Academy-Windows-Phone-app-to-Windows-8) on moving a Windows Phone application to Windows 8.

Comment: Thanks man, this link is useful too:
http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/02/24/patterns-for-sharing-code-in-windows-phone-and-windows-8-applications/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Portable Class libraries to share the code between Windows Phone app and Windows 8 application. It may helpful to reuse your written code which will be applicable for the platform that you have used while creating the PCL.

Comment: link: [Portable Class libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714086(v=vs.105).aspx) "can target multiple platforms, including Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Phone, Silverlight, and Xbox 360" Although Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 use similar XAML for UI, it isn't portable and cannot be put in a PCL.